# SlowCheetah is not transforming log4net.config files on Web Publish

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, publishing, slowcheetah

I have a web project is VS2013 that contains a publish profile called Test. I have `web.config` and a `web.test.config` along with `log4net.config` and `log4net.test.config` transform.

The web.config is transformed when the project is published (using VS2013 'Publish to File System') but the log4net config file isn't.

Do I need to adjust my Project file to ensure the transforms happen for non-web.config files during publish?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a [build configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) called "test". And when you build, this needs to be the active build configuration. I'm not sure but it might be case-sensitive so keep an eye out for that part.

[image]

Your publish profile also needs to refer to this build configuration.

[image]

You can also open up your .csproj file and ensure that SlowCheetah Targets are properly setup (file paths mainly).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had time to check this yet - will give it a go asap. But I awarded the bounty since it's about to expire and you're the top of the crop. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I am also having same issue. Tried this but still files are not transforming.

Comment: @sam: Can you give some more details? Maybe a separate question with your specific scenario? Its hard to guess things since there are so many variables.